# git send-email to not alter commit dates from git format-patch

Tags: git, email, date, patch

**Question:** Is there a way to tell `git send-email` to honor `git format-patch` dates?
Better still, is there way to not regard the mail date and commit date as distinct?

**Observations:** this is my observation about treating dates for which I have not found way to alter

1. Patches created with `git format-patch` have the commit date recorded as `Date:` header.
2. When using `git send-email` to send the patches, the commit date is changed to the moment of sending
3. When applying the commits with `git am`, the date as in `Date:` header of the received email is used.

**Partial work-around:** By using a wrapper script for `git send-email`, it is possible to extract the commit date from the patch and use `faketime` or similar method to force the `git send-email` to obey the commit date. This brings two problems, however:

1. Because the mail date and commit date are collapsed to one (which I regard as conceptual defect), the mail will appear in the inbox in wrong time which is inconvenient.
2. I can only easily apply this method to sending one patch, not a series of patches, if I want them to appear in the same mail thread. Okay, of course I can enable SMTP debugging (`git send-email --smtp-debug=1`) and extract the `Message-Id` from the output. But then it start to look like I need to start rewriting the threading options that are already implemented in `git send-email`...

Note that if `git send-email` would honor the commit dates recorded by `git format-patch` then I could use cover letter (`git send-email --cover-letter`) to deal with the problem number 1, relying on the threading support of the `git send-email` and MUAs.

**Bonus Question:**
I really would like to see the original commit (implementation) dates in the applied patches for record (series of patches merged in one commit would tell the time of incorporating to the published branch). Is my thinking somehow misguided in wanting this? *Is there some deeper thinking in treating the email date and commit date as one?* This to me is analogous to pushing local changes to some public branch - the dates are kept.

**P.S.** There is no tags `git-send-email` and `git-format-patch` which I would like to use (reputation will not allow creating them).

Comment: But I thought https://plus.google.com/u/1/101384639386588513837/posts/hAeTE7AYoVg was saying the opposite? ("When you do `git send-email` it uses the commit date as the email date field by default") Same in this old thread: http://osdir.com/ml/git/2009-01/msg00448.html

Comment: @VonC - thanks for the link! Very weird that different people have different behaviors for their `git send-email`. The mail list post seems to be about `git am` which is too late phase to fix anything (that's what got patched anyway).

Comment: Is there any chance that two different git versions are involved here? What's yours?

Comment: I have `git version 1.7.9.5` (as provided by Ubuntu 12.04). It is almost the same as the `master` branch `HEAD` version (you can check by yourself by `git log -w -p v1.7.9.5..HEAD git-send-email.perl`). There's new option about confirmation and quote parsing. Of course there is a miniscule possibility of code flow change somewhere I overlooked which results in date not modified... seems unlikely, though by quick look.

Comment: Interesting. I will have to do some test and see if I experiment the same date changes.

Comment: Do you still see the issue with Git 2.16.2?

Comment: @VonC - sorry, I have no idea. I do not at the moment have access to an environment to test the issue.

Comment: No problem, just curious. I was asking because I recently documented https://stackoverflow.com/a/48977563/6309